# Border color of margin instead of element

Tags: css

Can I style the border of the margin box instead of the element box itself?

Example:

```
|-------------------------------|
|                               |
|    |--------------------|     |
|    |                    |     |
|    |---box-color: red---|     |
|                               |
|---margin-border-color: blue---|
```

Comment: dont think so, use padding instead

Comment: @Tasos the problem is that I can't do `padding: auto;` instead of `margin: auto;`, which I'm using to center the content of the box element.

Comment: Margins, Padding and borders in one illustration: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/images/boxdim.png. **EDIT:** While you can't have a border on the "margin box" you can wrap it with another `div` and set a border. **BTW**, consider adding a jsfiddle.

Comment: It's really not clear what you are trying to do...a better explanation would be required. It's sounds to me more like you should be coloring the background of the **parent** rather than the element itself.

Comment: @Ofir Baruch: If the OP were able to create a working fiddle then they'd have answered their own question. It's pretty obvious why the OP chose to use ASCII art rather than a fiddle to illustrate their desired result.

Comment: @alexandernst, can you please provide a feedback regarding the provided answers? Is there a good answer that works for you or not?

Comment: @OfirBaruch Sorry, was AFK for a moment. The content of the box doesn't occupy the entire height/width of the box so I can't do the bg color trick. Anyways, I might do it with a nested box that would then hold all the elements.

Answer (score 1):

You should use padding if you need something like that.

For example:

```
<div class="box-around">
    <div class="box">
         some text here
    </div>
</div>
```

And then you can use `border-color` - which will work as normal border. And also `padding` on the element - to get the same effect. Like this.

```
.box {
   padding: 10px;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

If you want to center that element - then it is different question.

You can use some other method to center element. Like this:

```
.box-around {
    text-align: center;
}
.box {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

JsFiddle added: http://jsfiddle.net/zqr8113y/

Comment: The problem is that I can't do padding: auto; instead of margin: auto;, which I'm using to center the content of the box element

Comment: I updated my answer - it includes explanation how to center that box.

Comment: @alexandernst there is also jsfiddle now attached to the answer

Answer (score 1):

You may also use pseudo elements:

```
.borders {
  position: relative;
  border: 5px solid #f00;
}
.borders:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  border: 5px solid #ffea00;
}
```

[look here for more detail](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/multiple-borders/)

Comment: This might work, I need to try it. Will provide feedback after done testing.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, margin has no border. If you want to set border to the outside box since you want to use `margin: 0 auto`, you need to wrap your element and add border to the parent element. Example:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.inner {
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This uses fixed height, which I can't use.

Comment: Whats the problem with fixed height?

Comment: The problem with fixed height is... well... the fixed height itself. Fixed values are useless most of the time; even more in this particular case as I don't know how high the content will be.